# Mongodb update on nested document with sort and slice

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The document represents one users having images. Each image can have N images related to it. I would like to be able to update the matches list only if:

- The match does exist yet.
- There is less then N elements in the matches array
- If they are already N element, only push if "c" parameter is higher than the lower present.

```js
{
    "user_id" : 1,
    "imgs" : [
        {
            "img_id" : 1,
            "matches" : [
                {
                    "c" : 0.3,
                    "img_id" : 2
                },
                {
                    "c" : 0.2,
                    "img_id" : 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "img_id" : 5,
            "matches" : [
                {
                "c" : 0.4,
                "img_id" : 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, "matches" is a set, but $addToSet does not provide $slice and $sort, so I am trying to use $push instead.

```
db.stack.updateOne(
{ "user_id" : 1, "imgs.img_id" : 1, "imgs.matches.img_id" : { "$ne" : 2 } },
{ "$push" : { "imgs.$.matches" : { "$each" : [ { "c" : 0.7, "img_id" : 2} ], "$sort" : { "c" : -1 }, "$slice" : 3 } } }
);
```

Does not work, since my document get inserted several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the filter part of the updateOne. You should use $elemMatch to make sure that the filter is applied to only one element of the "matches" list.

```
{"user_id": 1, "imgs": {"$elemMatch": {"img_id" : 1, "matches.img_id": {"$ne": 2}}}}, 
{ "$push" : { "imgs.$.matches" : { "$each" : [ { "c" : 0.7, "img_id" : 2} ], "$sort" : { "c" : -1 }, "$slice" : 3 } } })
```